# "An Unknown error occurred" When trying to launch my Siri Shortcut

Tags: sirishortcuts

I am adding siri Shortcuts to my existing app.  There are three shortcuts, one to start the app with a specific value, one to increase the value by an amount and one to decrease the value by an amount. The shortcut code, for the start the app is attached here:

```
//
//  StartMeetingIntentHandler.swift
//


import Intents
import SwiftUI

class StartMeetingIntentHandler: NSObject, StartMeetingIntentHandling {


    @ObservedObject var meeting = Meeting()

    func handle(intent: StartMeetingIntent, completion: @escaping (StartMeetingIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        if let attendees = intent.attendees {
            meeting.meetingStarted()
            meeting.addAttendee(numberToAdd: Int(truncating: attendees))
            completion(StartMeetingIntentResponse.success(result: attendees))
        } else {
            print("failure")
        }
    }

    func resolveAttendees(for intent: StartMeetingIntent, with completion: @escaping (StartMeetingAttendeesResolutionResult) -> Void) {
        let people = Int(truncating: intent.attendees ?? 0)
        if people < 0 {
            completion(StartMeetingAttendeesResolutionResult.unsupported(forReason: StartMeetingAttendeesUnsupportedReason.negativeNumbersNotSupported))
        } else if people > 1000 {
            completion(StartMeetingAttendeesResolutionResult.unsupported(forReason: StartMeetingAttendeesUnsupportedReason.greaterThanMaximumValue))
        } else {
            completion(StartMeetingAttendeesResolutionResult.success(with: people))
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the shortcut from the Shortcuts app, I get the message "An unknown error has occurred".  How does one go about debugging that?

After reviewing the console for the simulator I found two errors:
1)

```
[INCExtensionRequest _extensionContextHost] Unexpected extension context class (null)
```

and 2)

```
-[WFAction runWithInput:userInterface:parameterInputProvider:variableSource:completionHandler:]_block_invoke Action <WFHandleCustomIntentAction: 0x7ffe845b1a10, identifier: com.theapapp.wastedtime.AddAttendeeIntent, parameters: 2> finished with error {domain: WFIntentExecutorErrorDomain, code: 103}. Error Domain=WFIntentExecutorErrorDomain Code=103 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred., WFIntentExecutorIntentResponseErrorKey=<INIntentResponse: 0x600003f63f80> {
    userActivity = <null>;
    code = INIntentResponseCodeFailure;
}, WFIntentExecutorIntentErrorKey=<INIntent: 0x6000018f0630> {
    people = 1;
}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could Not Run Add Attendee}
```

Comment: I have checked in the console and updated my question with the detailed error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this exact same error because I was accidentally returning my CustomIntent instead of my CustomIntentHandler in the IntentHandler.swift file

**Before:**

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        if intent is CustomIntent {
          return CustomIntent()
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

**After:**

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        if intent is CustomIntent {
          return CustomIntentHandler()
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: My app is a SwiftUI with both Watch, Catalyst, and iOS targets.  In my SiriExtentsions IntentHandler.Swift I am calling the CustomIntentHandler(), but in my SiriIntents IntentHandler.Swift it says that CustomIntentHandler() is invalid. But It does accept CustomIntent()

Comment: It appears that I am getting this error when I have a custom Intent that can accept a value.  When I process the custom Intent with no parameters, it seems to find the intent handler.  I have the Intent defined with a "Default" value in the Intent Definition, does this require that I change my intentHandler()?

Comment: Going to accept this answer.... I am now dealing with a different issue and will raise it separately.

Comment: @MichaelRowe Did you find the solution with custom intent accepting parameter issue?